# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance error in Angular2 form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, plunker

I am trying to create a basic form in Angular 2 on plunker but faced with the below error on Chrome Dev's Console:

```
VM8247:27 EXCEPTION: Error in ./App class App - inline template:1:12 caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

Plus there are some other errors also which point to more or less the above error only. **I came across other answers on SO related to this but most of them had typos in their code**.

Please have a look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BT8thPbmyW19nDWaOPHB?p=preview) .

Comment: Suggested close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a typo in your plunker...

Instead of

```
constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
```

You write

```
cosntructor(fb:FormBuilder){
```

That is why your form isn't getting initialized and remains undefined for Angular.

Comment: oooh man. Thanx for the slight fix. I don't know how I didn't see that, was more worried bout the errors. Angular should also give these type errors.

Comment: well, on typescript / angular side it is valid. Nobody restricts you in having function with the name `cosntructor` :D

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `FormGroup` instance empty at the time of declaration :

```
myFormGroup : FormGroup = new FormGroup({})
```